# How to specify IntelliJ Exclude Directories using Gradle?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Using IntelliJ to open a `build.gradle` file, in the "Import Project from Gradle" window, the "Excluded Roots" are pre-populated with the `.gradle` and `build` directories.

How do I specify what directories should be excluded (or not excluded) in the `build.gradle` file?

Specifically I am using a protocol buffer plugin that places generated sources in the `/build/generated-sources/` directory. If the `build` directory is excluded then my source class do not see the generated classes.

***Details:** IntelliJ 12.1.3, Gradle 1.4*

Comment: For people using the built in gradle import functionality in IDEA (i.e. not the gradle plugin) - go vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104847

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As shown in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html), you can configure the `idea.module.excludeDirs` property, which is of type `List<File>`. Apparently IDEA doesn't support including subdirectories of excluded directories, so you'll have to exclude all siblings of `build/generated-sources`. For example:

```
idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs = [file(".gradle")]
        ["classes", "docs", "dependency-cache", "libs", "reports", "resources", "test-results", "tmp"].each {
            excludeDirs << file("$buildDir/$it")
        }
    }
}
```

If supported by the Protocol Buffer plugin, it may be easier to put the generated sources into a place outside `build`, and make that place known to the `clean` task (e.g. `clean.delete "generated-sources"`).

Comment: Unfortunately the generated-sources directory is hard-coded into the plugin.

Comment: I am not using the Idea plugin for gradle, I am opening the project using the native functionality of IntelliJ 12. Will this work when I open it this way?

Comment: JetGradle apparently does look at this for setting up the project.

Answer (score 12):

Another solution. Works with Idea 13.

```
idea.module {
     excludeDirs -= file(buildDir) //1
     buildDir.listFiles({d,f->f != 'generated-sources'} as FilenameFilter).each {excludeDirs += it}} //2
```

1. Remove `buildDir` from `excludeDirs`.
2. Exclude each `buildDir` child (except `generating-source`).

Comment: I think this will only work if you run the `idea` task after you've generated the files under `build` - not on a clean checkout.

Comment: This is just management of included/excluded dirs in project layout.
Idea doesn't save layout of my gradle based project. And after it starts again, `buildDir` becomes excluded from layout again. And these few lines fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Gradle Kotlin DSL, use the following snippet:

```
idea {
  module {
    excludeDirs.add(file("..."))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for exclude folder in module i'm use

```
idea {
    module.apply {
        val file = file("$projectDir/node_modules")
        val exclude = HashSet<File>(excludeDirs)
        exclude.add(file)
        excludeDirs = exclude
    }
}
```