# IntelliJ: Excluding a set of folders across multiple Gradle modules in an IntelliJ Gradle project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I need to figure out a quick/scripted way of excluding a set of folders across multiple IntelliJ gradle modules in an IntelliJ project imported from Gradle.

I have a Gradle multi-module project that I have imported into IntelliJ.  The project is a refactoring of a legacy codebase into modules.  Part of the resulted refactoring is that there are multiple copies of the same class across multiples modules (this was done to break dependency cycles in code): there is the original class and a number of "mock" copies

I'm trying to exclude a bunch of folders containing copies of classes in these "mock" sourcesets in a scripted manner.

I've imported the Gradle project into InteliJ.  To begin excluding the folders I started by excluding one of the folders in one of the modules... ...

I then tried to determine where in my .idea folder this particular setting is persisted... I have been unable to find it...

My question is: can someone point me to the IntelliJ file (e.g. .idea/workspace.xml) that stores this setting?  Alternatively can someone point me to the folder that stores this setting?

*Update*

I manually went and excluded all the folders that contain mock copies of my classes.  Those settings appear to be persisted (still not sure where those settings are being stored).

The second problem I need to solve is that I need to declare custom dependencies between Gradle imported modules that are different from those configured in the Gradle project.  I can add dependencies within the project, but whenever I refresh my Gradle project or import any changes, my changes are lost.

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702526/104891)?

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder ... Yes, that came up in my search.  That answer appears to be referring to a configuration of the [Gradle IDEA plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html).  In my scenario, we're importing the Gradle project directly into IntelliJ, and therefore we're not using the IDEA plugin.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is using this configuration when importing the project.

Comment: @CrazyCoder ....eeeeeee-interesting ... I'll put in on my todo list to investigate this further when I have time. I've devised a workaround for the time being -- I've declared a single IntelliJ manual module and added all the Gradle module sourceset folders and content roots to my module