# Android Studio: How to exclude Doc Folder from Search and other functionality?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

I have a huge auto-generated documentation folder in my Android project.

Unfortunately, all the auto-generated doc files clutter the refactoring and search functionality of Android Studio (e.g. rename, find references, search and replace).

An obvious solution would be to move the entire Android Studio project to a subfolder of the git repo, but I want to avoid this route.

How can I make Android Studio ignore a selected documentation folder?

I have one more requirement: The solution must work for all fellow developers who clone the repo. I do not want any configuration that must be manually applied for each developer machine.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702526/104891 help?

Comment: see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206183859-What-are-the-various-types-that-I-can-mark-a-directory-as- and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html

Comment: for your second part just push the android config to git for other machines to use

Comment: @CrazyCode I am not a Gradle guru, but I think that this does not work for Android Studio.

Comment: What do you mean with "android config"? I believe that the solutions should by applied by gradle. All the .idea/ and *.iml stuff is regenerated when "syncing with gradle".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet works for Android Studio 3.5.
Put this into your root level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs += file('mydocfolder')
    }
}
```

Then sync with gradle and `mydocfolder` should appear in a different color in the project view.
Note that `excludeDirs.add(file('mydocfolder'))` does *not* work.