# How can make IntelliJ recognize "exclude" files in Gradle's plugin ShadowJar when debugging?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, shadowjar

I want to debug my Java application which is managed by Gradle and packed by Gradle's plugin shadowJar. I exclude some files in shadowJar task in `build.gradle`, however, these files are not excluded when I run debug in IntelliJ. So is there any way to tell IntelliJ to exclude these files when debugging? I'm sure my code in `build.gradle` is right because I can use the command line to build the right jar package.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    exclude 'config/audit.yml'
    exclude 'config/body.yml'
    exclude 'config/client.yml'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting **Gradle** as Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using**? This should work. If it works with Gradle then it should work in IDE with this option.

Comment: Alternatively use `idea` Gradle plugin to exclude certain directories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702526/2000323

Comment: @Andrey I've set IntelliJ's setting "Build and run using Gradle", but it doesn't work. I think IntelliJ's debug package task is different from shadowJar task, so the exclude statements in shadowJar task would never be run when debug in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Andrey Thank you, Andrey. However, I think using `idea` plugin to exclude files is not a good idea in my case, because I need to write almost the same exclude codes in both `idea` block and shadowJar block...