# Intellij : How to exclude file of particular types from indexing

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, idea-gradle-plugin

I am working on an android project in Android Studio.
My project uses a lot of `*.cpp` and `*.hpp` files.
So when I open my project , Android Studio starts indexing the `*.cpp` files and becomes very slow.
I tried this in `gradle`:

```
idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs += file '*.cpp; *.hpp; *.h'
    }
}
```

but it is not working. Is there a way to prevent indexing of particular file types from indexing in gradle?

Comment: You should exclude specific directory. Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702526/2000323

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will affect ALL projects (as this setting is IDE-wide)

Settings | File Types | Ignore files and folders field at the bottom of that setting page.

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/file-types.html

[image]